# Server stored, encypted messaging app

Tags: encryption, rsa, aes, diffie-hellman, man-in-the-middle

For my personal research, I have to create a messaging app, but security is only important part of application, security from MITM (man in the middle attack), at device end, and at server level. (note: this will not end to end encryption, as I want to backup messages on server for cross-device access like telegram).

I created the following model:

```
Server creates RSA key pair first time at installation and keeps private key in a file on server, and broadcast public key with its clients, (A, B)
A&B also create RSA key pair at first-time login, and stores private key at device level and sends public key to server.
A sending message to B:
    create a random salt_key
    encrypt message with this salt_key (AES)
    encrypt salt_key with server's public key (RSA)
    send RSA encrypted key, and AES encrypted message to server
    server can decrypt salt_key with RSA private key and then message
    server will do same as A did, but with B's public key and B will decrypt salt_key with private key then decrypt message.
```

I Will also add "signature" for sender verification, but my concern is **SERVER** because if server compromised everything the-end, but if i choose end to end encryption, how to achieve my message backup goal and cross device, access.

Comment: You definitely want to add signatures in to prevent MiTM attacks

Comment: A PGP-like model would be best here; It's public, symmetric, and easy to add authentication.

Comment: Edited, made some changes please look into. thanks